# Incomplete file when downloading with Java from FTP

Tags: java, ftp, download

In my application I upload a byte[] (serialized Object) to my FTP server, which is working perfectly. However when I try to download it only the first part (like 3000 bytes) of the array are correct, the rest is filled with zeros.

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, any help would be appreciated.
I am using the package
    org.apache.commons.net.*

```
public static byte[] downloadBoard( String host, int port, String usr, String pwd) throws IOException {
  FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
  byte[] buf = new byte[20000];

  try {
    ftpClient.connect( host, port );
    ftpClient.login( usr, pwd );

    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    InputStream is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("asdf.board");
    is.read(buf);
    is.close();

    ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
    ftpClient.logout();
  } finally {
    ftpClient.disconnect();
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is.read() may not return the full content. You'll need to put read() into a loop similar to this:

```
int pos = 0;
while (true) {
  int count = is.read(buf, pos, buf.length - pos);
  if (count <= 0) {
    break;
  }
  pos += count;
}
```

P.S.:

If you know the size of the file, you can use a DataInputStream to read the buffer without a loop:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[exactFileSize];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
dis.readFully(buf);
```

Comment: -1 <= 0 was true last time I checked. is.read() will return 0 when buf.length == pos, i.e when the buffer is full (which probably should be an error case here).

Comment: BTW: If you don't know the (maximum) file size, you may want to copy the data to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then get the byte array from there. ByteArrayOutputStream expands an internal buffer as needed while data is added.

Comment: Along those lines, check out IOUtils.copy() and DeferredFileOutputStream from Apache Commons IO. http://commons.apache.org/

Comment: I never suggested that `(-1 <= 0)` was other than `true`. Only that the method returns `-1` to indicate something specific. Your `if` test hides that.

Answer (score 2):

`InputStream.read()` typically **doesn't** read the entire stream for you, only some part of it. Note that [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) returns the number of bytes **actually read**, which you'll need to check.

The typical pattern is to loop until the `InputStream` has reported that no more bytes are available.